# Store the data after SSIS package execution

Tags: database, ssis, store, execution

I have a source file(text file) which is taken and executed through SSIS package. This is done daily on a schedule basis using SQL Server Agent. After each execution as a new file is created on destination folder, I am looking for a way to keep and store the 14 day old data somewhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you are looking for?  Do you want to store 14 days worth of data that was imported from the files, store a copy of the files that went to the destination folder, but only 14 days worth?  Archive the destination files?

Comment: I am looking to store the files(14 days worth of data) that went to the destination folder everyday

Comment: So the obvious answer is store a copy of the file in another folder, though I'm gathering that you may have a more specific question.  Is it that you want an idea of how to limit that to 14 days worth or how can this be done with SSIS?